# Type mismatch in Redeclaration

Tags: c, type-mismatch, redeclaration

I have been able to remove almost all errors except these 5 errors in this C program (too long to paste so providing link).

http://codepad.org/AfqrDojN

The errors I receive are as follows:

[image: screenshot]

I am using the following libraries:

```
#include <graphics.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <conio.h>
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Why in the world are you using a 20+ year old IDE?

Comment: If it's *too long to paste*, then you should [make it minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not post a link.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have it all in one file?  SPLIT IT UP by function, or by related functions.

Comment: @CoolGuy Can you suggest a free IDE for C?

Comment: @user1089173,[Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are redefining the function `remove` that is already declared in

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

changing the name of your function to (for example) `void myremove()` will probably solve your problem.

Comment: The important point is that it is part of the standard C library.

Comment: Awesome. I just have the 2nd Error coming now on Line 48. Any clues?

Comment: at first: if this answer solved your question; you might accept it (to show everyone that the work is done)

Comment: second: if you have another question; better ask a new one. But before asking the new question; please have look around on the internet and in existing questions... many answers are already there.

Comment: It's the same question and applies to the same image I posted above. All errors are resolved by renaming the function except for the 2nd one on Line 48. It is not a new question.

Comment: whell in any case this is a quite different question. I guess you might be compiling with an old c-compiler, which doesn't allow definitions (eg `int a;`) anywhere in the code; only at the start of each function (or maybe also at the start of a block; not sure).